# Sliding button animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, controls

Is there something in WPF that would allow me to make buttons partially pop out of the screen ? Like I would do on a website with JQuery.

Part of the buttons would be popping out :

```
######################################
#utton||                             #
#                                    #
#utton||                             #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
######################################
```

And then when I mous over the button, it slides out :

```
######################################
#|| My Button||                      #
#                                    #
#utton||                             #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
#                                    #
######################################
```

I can't seem to find a good way to implement this as it doesn't seem to be doable with basic WPF controls.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to be doable` - You can do that in 3 lines of XAML using a `RenderTransform` and an animation. Before saying something `doesn't seem to be doable` - at least go ahead and try it.

Comment: BTW, yes, jQuery/jQuery UI are awesome libraries. The only reason I would go into any web stuff anyday.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use a [`TranslateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and animate its `X` property.  Give it an initial negative value, and then animate it to zero on mouseover.

So you should have something like this:

```
<Button Content="MyButton">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" X="-20" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

Then, animate `(TranslateTransform.X)` using your preferred method (EventTrigger, VisualState, etc).  Here's an example using event triggers:

```
<Button Content="MyButton">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" X="-20" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.3">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="translate" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                     To="0">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase />
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.3">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="translate" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                     To="-20">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase />
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Awesome. Xaml is so powerful.. about time I switched to it. I will read about it a little more now. Thanks a lot ! works perfectly.